# including DDK headers

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, wdk

I'm having a bit of trouble including headers from Windows Driver Kit to Visual Studio 2010. Can anyone help me, what I am doing wrong?

I get error message such as C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sal.h': No such file or directory. 
If I include SDK directory, I get error messages such as type redefinitions. 
If I copy sal.h to DDK directory, I get error message C1083: Cannot open include file: 'codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h': No such file or directory. 
If I copy sourceannotations.h file to DDK directory I get other error messages (see below)

VC++ Directoy settings: [include directory settings](http://i40.tinypic.com/4o76.png)

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <fwpmu.h>
#include <ndis.h>

Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h': No such file or directory    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\crt\sal.h    160 1   wfp
2   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h"    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\crt\sal.h    160 1   
21  IntelliSense: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone  c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\ntddk.h  2895    1   
22  IntelliSense: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone  c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\ntddk.h  2907    1   
23  IntelliSense: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone  c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\ntddk.h  2917    1   
8   IntelliSense: expected a ')'    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\fwptypes.h   345 49  
6   IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\fwptypes.h   281 4   
9   IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\fwptypes.h   364 1   
11  IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\iketypes.h   370 1   
16  IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\wdm.h    8838    1   
25  IntelliSense: expected a declaration    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\ntddk.h  15056   5   
4   IntelliSense: expected a type specifier c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\fwptypes.h   275 18  
3   IntelliSense: expected an identifier    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\fwptypes.h   275 5   
7   IntelliSense: expected an identifier    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\fwptypes.h   345 5   
10  IntelliSense: expected an identifier    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\iketypes.h   369 2   
18  IntelliSense: expected an identifier    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\wdm.h    17964   1   
19  IntelliSense: expected an identifier    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\wdm.h    17970   9   
24  IntelliSense: expected an identifier    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\ntddk.h  15037   3   
14  IntelliSense: identifier "FWP_FILTER_ENUM_TYPE" is undefined    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\fwpmtypes.h  413 5   
12  IntelliSense: identifier "IKEEXT_IP_VERSION_SPECIFIC_KEYMODULE_STATISTICS0" is undefined    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\iketypes.h   418 5   
13  IntelliSense: identifier "IKEEXT_IP_VERSION_SPECIFIC_KEYMODULE_STATISTICS0" is undefined    c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\iketypes.h   419 5   
20  IntelliSense: identifier "PCALLBACK_FUNCTION" is undefined  c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\wdm.h    17994   10  
17  IntelliSense: identifier "TIME_FIELDS" is undefined c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\wdm.h    9012    9   
15  IntelliSense: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier   c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\wdm.h    8837    1   
5   IntelliSense: unexpected parenthesis after declaration of function "<error>" (malformed parameter list or invalid initializer?) c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\fwptypes.h   278 4
```

Comment: Have you tried reordering the includes? windows.h at the top and "stdafx.h" last?

Comment: Not putting stdafx.h on top has, erm, interesting effects.

Comment: @Niklas Hansson it isn't solution

Comment: @Niklas Hansson I tried it, but i got other error messages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant' mix the headers from the SDK with the ones from the DDK.

So uncheck the box for inheriting parent settings. May then you have to add other directories from the DDK.

Also note that you also can't mix libraries from the DDK with the ones from the SDK. So you have to do there almost the same.